# Concatenation of php variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": 'https://example.com/something.aspx?i='<? echo urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>,
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  }
}
```

It doesn't work this way, the concatenation is wrong I think. Tried few ways still doesn't work.

Comment: `"crossDomain": true,` — This almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. Look it up and decide if you really need it.

Comment: If you looked at what the browser received, surely it would have been fairly clear what was wrong.

Comment: `'https://example.com/something.aspx?i=' + <? echo urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>`

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the data **inside** the JavaScript string literal. Move the `'` to after the extra data you are outputting.

Answer (score 3):

You just had the single quote the wrong side.

Don't forget you're outputting to HTML, so you don't have to concatenate a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": 'https://example.com/something.aspx?i=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>',
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try it the other way round. Like

```
<?php
  echo 'var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://example.com/something.aspx?i='.urlencode($_GET['id']).'",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }
  }'; 
?>
```

Please note the changes I made with the ' and " in the `url` attribute.

Comment: You're still closing the `" .. "` string here, so this won't work.